# Bash passing arguments to a C code with ${variable}

Tags: bash, variables, arguments

I have a problem with my bash script not working because it doesn't translate a ${var} to its value.

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash

make huffmanTree.exe
file="timesSeq.txt"
echo "Times Huffman Tree Sequential" > ${file}
echo "" >> ${file}

function fn_calculate_times {
    for i in ${folder}/*.*
    do
        echo ${i} times >> ${file}
        avg=0
        for j in {1..5}
        do
            start=`date +%s`
            echo "${folder}/${i}"
            ./huffmanTree.exe "$folder/$i"
            end=`date +%s`
            echo "    time = `expr $end - $start` s >> ${file}"
            avg=`expr $avg + $end - $start`
        done;
        echo "    average = `expr $avg / $j`"
    done;
    echo "" >> ${file}
}

echo "TXT's" >> ${file}
folder="test-texts"
fn_calculate_times

echo "IMG's" >> ${file}
folder="test-images"
fn_calculate_times
```

My output (this multiple times):

> test-images/test-images/img-input-200MB.jpg
>   ERROR: file couldn't be opened.
>       time = 0 s >> timesSeq.txt
>       average = 0

Seems like $folder/$i isn't translated to test-texts/text-name.txt
- The rest of the script seems to work.
- I've tried using {} to ${folder}/${i). Same result.
- I'm on a Mac.

What am I missing?

//SOLVED: read comments.

Comment: Maybe use quotes to secure the content of the variables. There are hyphens in them that the c code argument parser might misunderstand as options. so try `"${folder}/${i}"` instead? What is in the `${i}` really the filename?

Comment: @Dilettant - That won't make any difference to anything that the C executable does.

Comment: I copied your script, made a `ln -s /bin/echo huffmanTree.exe`, commented out that make line,  created these folders touched files "into" them, and I see as output nice lines like: `test-texts/test-texts/a_text.txt` five times with time measurement, and the matching five line groups on the other folders single file I created. Also using OS X and `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)` do you have special glob option settting? Like `set -f` in effect?

Comment: OK. Found the problem! the $i in $folder/*.* was taking the whole var "$folder/*.*" when I thought it was only the "\*.\*" therefore at passing argument as $folder/$i was repeating the $folder part hehe.

Comment: @p4x please make your solution an answer and mark it accepted so others won't see this as an open question, and future readers will see your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem! the $i in $folder/*.* was taking the whole var "$folder/*.*" when I thought it was only the "*.*" therefore at passing argument as $folder/$i was repeating the $folder part hehe.

The correct code:

```
#!/bin/bash

make huffmanTree.exe
file="timesSeq.txt"
echo "Times Huffman Tree Sequential" > ${file}
echo "" >> ${file}

function fn_calculate_times {
    for i in ${folder}/*.*
    do
        echo ${i} times >> ${file}
        avg=0
        for j in {1..5}
        do
            start=`date +%s`
            echo "${folder}/${i}"
            ./huffmanTree.exe "$i"
            end=`date +%s`
            echo "    time = `expr $end - $start` s >> ${file}"
            avg=`expr $avg + $end - $start`
        done;
        echo "    average = `expr $avg / $j`"
    done;
    echo "" >> ${file}
}

echo "TXT's" >> ${file}
folder="test-texts"
fn_calculate_times

echo "IMG's" >> ${file}
folder="test-images"
fn_calculate_times
```